# Android. Espresso: How write test check is text is underlined on TextView?

Tags: android-espresso

Here my xml layout:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/forgotPasswordTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="@{ () -> presenter.doForgotPassword()}"
            android:text="@string/forgot_password"
            android:textColor="#bbbbbb"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/loginTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/loginTextView" />
```

Here @string/forgot_password

```
<string name="forgot_password"><u>Forgot password?</u></string>
```

As result text in underlined. Nice.

But I want to write Espresso test to check is text in **TextView** is underline?How I can do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an Espresso test then just create a new matcher as the following:

```
public static Matcher<View> withUnderlinedText() {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView.class) {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(TextView textView) {
                CharSequence charSequence = textView.getText();
                UnderlineSpan[] underlineSpans = ((SpannedString) charSequence).getSpans(0, charSequence.length(), UnderlineSpan.class);

                return underlineSpans != null && underlineSpans.length > 0;    
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
        }
    };
}
```

And use it as below:

```
onView(withId(R.id.forgotPasswordTextView)).check(matches(withUnderlinedText()));
```